# Serialize Json.net back to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

How do I take a `Json.net` object and turn it back into a string of json?
I deserialize a json packet that I get from a rest service. Then I process it and end up with  an array of `JObject`s. But then I need to turn it back into a JSON string to send it to the browser.

If I had regular objects then I could just call `JsonConvert.Serialize()` but that doesn't work on `Json.net` `JObjects`

Comment: Perhaps JsonConvert.Serialize(JObjects.ToString()) will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `JObject`, or a `JArray` containing `JObjects`, you can simply call `ToString()` on the `JObject` (or `JArray`) to get the JSON string.  For example:

```
JObject jo = new JObject();
jo.Add("foo", "bar");
jo.Add("fizz", "buzz");

JObject jo2 = new JObject();
jo2.Add("foo", "baz");
jo2.Add("fizz", "bang");

JArray ja = new JArray();
ja.Add(jo);
ja.Add(jo2);

string json = ja.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Resulting JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "fizz": "buzz"
  },
  {
    "foo": "baz",
    "fizz": "bang"
  }
]
```

If you have a regular array of JObjects, you can pass it to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`:

```
JObject[] arrayOfJObjects = new JObject[] { jo, jo2 };
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayOfJObjects, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

This gives exactly the same JSON output as shown above.

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` also works fine on a single `JObject`:

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "fizz": "buzz"
}
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed the ASP.NET MVC tag on your question.

If you're inside an MVC controller method then presumably you are doing something like this:

```
return Json(arrayOfJObjects);
```

which will not work.  This is because MVC uses the `JavaScriptSerializer`, which does not know about Json.Net `JObjects`.  What you need to do in this case is create your JSON using one of the methods I listed above, then return it from your controller method using the `Content` method like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayOfJObjects);

return Content(json, "application/json");
```

Comment: Don't newer version of asp.net use json.net instead of the ``JavaScriptSerializer``?

Comment: @KyleGobel Web API uses Json.Net, but MVC still uses the JavaScriptSerializer for backward compatability reasons.